# Boris Johnson Partygate Report: What are the possible consequences for Johnson?

Tags: united-kingdom, covid-19, house-of-commons, boris-johnson

As I type this, the debate is ongoing over Boris Johnson, deciding whether or not to accept the Partygate report's findings.

The report suggests a 90-day suspension, possibly triggering a by-election, both of which are no longer really a "punishment" or relevant as he has resigned, so would be purely symbolic.

Given that the report has now passed the House, what does the punishment look like for Johnson for having been found to have lied to the House?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Now that the recommendations of the [report of the privileges committee](https://committees.parliament.uk/publications/40412/documents/197199/default/) have been adopted without amendment, Boris Johnson will receive the only sanction left available to the Commons now that he has resigned as an MP; the removal of his entitlement to a former member's pass. Former members may apply for this pass, which allows them limited access to the parliamentary estate without the need to be escorted, and the ability to use certain facilities within.

As Johnson has resigned as an MP, the other sanctions which would have been available to the committee - a time-based suspension from the house, or indeed an outright expulsion - were no longer relevant and did not form part of the report's sanction recommendations. The report puts on the record, though, that had Johnson not resigned, a suspension of 90 days from the House would have been recommended, which would have triggered a recall petition under the [Recall of MPs Act 2015](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2015/25/contents). This would have triggered a by-election if signed by more than 10% of the electorate in his constituency. Putting this sanction on the record provides at the very least, some sort of precedent for the seriousness and appropriate punishment for future investigations of this type to consider.

Your question talks about a possible by-election; Johnson's resignation makes this not just a possibility, but a certainty:- the writ of election has already been issued in his former constituency of Uxbridge and South Ruislip, and will take place in late July. There is nothing stopping Johnson from running in this election (although he would probably have to do so as an independent candidate, rather than as a Conservative party candidate).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this perfectly clears up a lot of the misunderstandings I had about the report and the imposition of it providing it passes!

Comment: I would add that the resignation should probably be viewed as part of the punishment. It wasn’t imposed, but a resignation to avoid the possibility of a recall petition is kind of like a minister who resigns instead of being fired.

Comment: Would getting re-elected "cleanse" Boris Johnson from his past crimes?

Comment: @JonathanReez: No. His reputation remains terrible, and Conservative MPs won't trust him.

Comment: @JonathanReez agree with John Dallman that his reputation seems pretty unsalvagable, but cleanse in the sense that he can't be suspended from the House for the transgressions detailed in the report - yes.

Comment: @JohnDallman But even accepting that he has a terrible reputation and isn't trusted by the people who worked with him, and leaving aside the number of people nationally who despise him, was he a sufficiently good constituency MP that he could potentially get reelected on that record?

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd  Johnson has only voted on three occasions since he lost the leadership of the Conservative party, he's rarely in the House and spends most of his time at speaking events, many overseas:  https://www.opendemocracy.net/en/boris-johnson-millions-prime-minister-earnings/

Comment: @DaveGremlin But he could still be a good consituency MP by virtue of the people in his local office and their handling of constituents' problems.

Comment: Will the lack of a pass reduce his value as a newspaper columnist?

Comment: @AndrewMorton  He'll be able to visit the Houses of Parliament as the guest of an MP or a member of the House of Lords, probably one of the people he's just enobled in his honours list.

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd  A good constituency MP uses their position to raise constituency issues with the government, civil service institutions and organisations.  Johnson, by virtue of his personality, could have a terrific influence but I doubt he has the time since he's busy writing his memoir, after-dinner speeches, traveling the world to deliver lectures etc.  His office staff may be excellent administrators on his behalf but they're not him and won't have the same impact.  Also, if a Tory wins the by-election and retains Johnson's staff, would that make them a good constituency MP by default?

Comment: According to Chris Bryant - who I'd expect to know - if Boris ever returned to the house, he would immediately have the 90 day suspension applied to him.

Comment: @JackAidley could you link me to where he said that? That certainly runs contrary to my understanding of it -

Comment: @DaveGremlin Yes, but there's a lot of "could have" and "I doubt" in there: sentiment with which, to be honest, I am in full agreement /but/ which doesn't provide a definitive answer.